# How to "embed" Piecewise in NDSolve in Mathematica 

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, piecewise

1. I am using `NDSolve` to solve a non-linear partial differential
   equation.
2. I'd like one of the variables (Kvar) to be a function
   of the time step currently being solved and hence and using
   `Piecewise`.
3. Mathematica generates an error message saying:

> SetDelayed::write: Tag Real in 0.05[t_] is Protected. >>
>   NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of
>   $Failed in the first argument ....
>
> ReplaceAll::reps: ....

I haven't included the entire error message for ease of reading.

My code is as follows:

```
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
Clear[Eq4, EvapThickFilm, h, S, G, E1, K1, D1, VR, M, R]
Eq4[h_, {S_, G_, E1_, K1_, D1_, VR_, M_, R_}] := \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]h\) + 
    Div[-h^3 G Grad[h] + 
      h^3 S Grad[Laplacian[h]] + (VR E1^2 h^3)/(D1 (h + K1)^3)
        Grad[h] + M (h/(1 + h))^2 Grad[h]] + E1/(
    h + K1) + (R/6) D[D[(h^2/(1 + h)), x] h^3, x] == 0;
SetCoordinates[Cartesian[x, y, z]];
EvapThickFilm[S_, G_, E1_, K1_, D1_, VR_, M_, R_] := 
  Eq4[h[x, y, t], {S, G, E1, K1, D1, VR, M, R}];
TraditionalForm[EvapThickFilm[S, G, E1, K1, D1, VR, M, R]];
```

And the second cell where I am trying to implement `Piecewise` in `NDSolve`:

```
L = 318; TMax = 7.0;
Off[NDSolve::mxsst];
(*Ktemp = Array[0.001+0.001#^2&,13]*)
hSol = h /. NDSolve[{
     (*S,G,E,K,D,VR,M*)

 Kvar[t_] :=  Piecewise[{{0.01, t <= 4}, {0.05, t > 4}}],
 EvapThickFilm[1, 3, 0.1, Kvar[t], 0.01, 0.1, 0, 160],
 h[0, y, t] == h[L, y, t],
 h[x, 0, t] == h[x, L, t],
 (*h[x,y,0] == 1.1+Cos[x] Sin[2y] *)

 h[x, y, 0] == 
  1 + (-0.25 Cos[2 \[Pi] x/L] - 0.25 Sin[2 \[Pi] x/L]) Cos[
     2 \[Pi] y/L]
 },
h,
{x, 0, L},
{y, 0, L},
{t, 0, TMax}
][[1]]

hGrid = InterpolatingFunctionGrid[hSol];
```

PS: I am sorry but the first cell block doesn't display so well here. And thanks to not having enough "reputation", I can't post images.

The error message occurs when using the `NDSolve` cell block.

Comment: Take the definition of Kvar[t_] out of the NDSolve argument list. it will then give a solution. Might need to massage NDSolve settings to get better error estimate and have it run successfully to TMax (seems to quit around 2.36).

Comment: Thank you! That certainly helped. Like you suggested, next I'll try to play around with NDSolve settings. Any suggestions?

Comment: Preferably, you shouldn't use variables names starting with an uppercase letter as that may cause conflicts with built-in names (that all start with a capital letter). The line `TraditionalForm[EvapThickFilm[S, G, E1, K1, D1, VR, M, R]];` doesn't make sense. There is no assignment and the ; supresses any output. Hence there is no net effect.

Comment: The only reason I suppressed the "TraditionalForm[...]" was because the output was too long and not so easy on the eye.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the function `Kvar` outside of a set of equations in `NDSolve`, like

```
Off[NDSolve::mxsst];
(*Ktemp=Array[0.001+0.001#^2&,13]*)
Kvar[t_] := Piecewise[{{0.01, t <= 4}, {0.05, t > 4}}];
hSol = ...
```

and remove it from the list in `NDSolve`, so that it starts as `NDSolve[{(*S,G,E,K,D,VR,M*)EvapThickFilm[...`, and it will work. It gives warnings, but those are related to possible singularities in your equation.

Also, your original error indicates that your `Kvar` was assigned a value of `0.05`. So, add `Clear[Kvar]` before anything else in the second cell.